# Struggling adding WHERE clause to INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join, where-clause

I have a query which is supposed to select the lowest `price_per_pax_after_tax` from every `backend_hotels_id` `date_start` and `package_supplier` and this appears to be working until I add a WHERE clause.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT e.price_per_pax_after_tax, e.hotel_score, e.package_id, e.package_type
FROM packages_sorted_YQU e
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT db_id, MIN( price_per_pax_after_tax ) AS lowest_price, package_id, hotel_score
  FROM `packages_sorted_YQU`
  WHERE `package_type` IN ('9', '10', '18') 
  AND `package_duration` IN ('6', '8', '12')
  GROUP BY 
    `date_start` , `package_supplier` , `backend_hotels_id`
) AS j 
ON j.db_id = e.db_id
AND j.lowest_price= e.price_per_pax_after_tax
AND j.hotel_score = e.hotel_score
AND j.package_id = e.package_id;
```

The table is huge but all of the fields listed are INT except for `date_start` which is DATE

The where clause causing the problem is:

```
WHERE `package_type` IN ('9', '10', '18') 
AND `package_duration` IN ('6', '8', '12')
```

Without the where clause I get over 400 results and with the where clause I get zero results :( Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: sure packages types and durations with those ids actually exist?

Comment: How many results are you expecting to get?

Comment: How many results  you need to get

Comment: The package_types and package_durations do exist in at least one of the IN parameters for each field. e.g. package_type 10 AND package_duration 12 - according to my spreadsheet I should be getting at least 200 results.

Comment: In the end, all you have is `SELECT * FROM packages_sorted_YQU WHERE package_type IN (9, 10, 18) AND package_duration IN (6, 8, 12)`. Run this query to make sure there are actually matching rows.

Comment: if package_type is int, you could say  "WHERE `package_type` IN (9,10,18)", and skip a char-to-int conversion.  Perhaps you need to specify e.package_type if there is redundancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery:

```
  SELECT db_id
       , MIN( price_per_pax_after_tax ) AS lowest_price
       , package_id
       , hotel_score
  FROM `packages_sorted_YQU`
  WHERE `package_type` IN ('9', '10', '18') 
  AND `package_duration` IN ('6', '8', '12')
  GROUP BY 
       `date_start` 
     , `package_supplier` 
     , `backend_hotels_id`
```

will yield indeterminate results, with or without the `WHERE` clause. Because you are grouping by `date_start, package_supplier, backend_hotels_id` and have in the `SELECT` list columns without any aggregate functions on them: `db_id, package_id, hotel_score`.

This query should work consistently if the `(date_start, package_supplier, backend_hotels_id)` is the Primary Key or Unique.

Which is the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table and are there any other `UNIQUE` keys?

Answer (score 1):

If your columns `package_type` and `package_duration` are of type `int` you don't have to wrap the values inside `'` like strings.

```
SELECT e.price_per_pax_after_tax, e.hotel_score, e.package_id, e.package_type
FROM packages_sorted_YQU e
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT db_id, MIN( price_per_pax_after_tax ) AS lowest_price, package_id, hotel_score
  FROM `packages_sorted_YQU`
  WHERE `package_type` IN (9, 10, 18) 
  AND `package_duration` IN (6, 8, 12)
  GROUP BY 
    `date_start` , `package_supplier` , `backend_hotels_id`
) AS j 
ON j.db_id = e.db_id
AND j.lowest_price= e.price_per_pax_after_tax
AND j.hotel_score = e.hotel_score
AND j.package_id = e.package_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi all and thank you for your valuable input. I've solved the problem without a sub-query and it works a bit faster too.

```
SELECT MIN
(
    concat
    (
        LPAD(`price_per_pax_after_tax` , 5, '0'),
        LPAD(`package_id` , 12, '0'),
        LPAD(`hotel_score` , 7, '0')
    )
) AS cat
FROM `packages_sorted_YQU`
WHERE `package_type` IN
(
    9, 10, 18
)
AND `package_duration` IN
(
    6, 7, 8
)
GROUP BY `date_start` , `package_supplier` , `backend_hotels_id`
```

Then in PHP I break apart the concatenation with:

```
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($q,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $a[lrp][] = intval(substr($r[cat], 0, 5));
    $a[package_id][] = intval(substr($r[cat], 5, 12));
    $a[hotel_score][] = substr($r[cat], 17, 7);
}
```

I was lucky that the only FLOAT value was the `hotel_score` so I put that last - the other two were of type INT